# How to shift the starting point of the X axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a dataframe containing 365 observations of a variable, and 365 dates, one for each day of the year.

I want to plot this sequence using ggplot, but I want the plot to begin at an arbitrary date mid-way through the year, and plot all 365 observations, with the dates before the starting point appearing at the end of the sequence.

What can I do, either to the dataframe itself, or to the plot aesthetics, to achieve this?

#### Updated with reproducible data and more context

Below is example code which should illustrate how I ended up with this problem.

```
#ten years of data ordered by hydro year

dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-10-01"), as.Date("2010-10-01"), by="days")    
values <- runif(3653)    
df = data.frame(Date=as.Date(dates), Val=values)

> head(df)
        Date       Val
1 2000-10-01 0.9868603
2 2000-10-02 0.6461032
3 2000-10-03 0.7823848
4 2000-10-04 0.9914216
5 2000-10-05 0.8171412
6 2000-10-06 0.3213551

#created new df containing the average of all ten years of measurements for each day of the year

df2 <- df %>% mutate(Day=day(dates), Month =month(dates)) %>%    
group_by(Month, Day) %>%    
summarize(Multiyearmean=mean(Val))

> head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Month [1]
  Month   Day Multiyearmean
  <dbl> <int>         <dbl>
1     1     1         0.272
2     1     2         0.577
3     1     3         0.269
4     1     4         0.534
5     1     5         0.607
6     1     6         0.649
```

My values are still associated with the correct month and day dates, but they are now ordered Jan-Dec, instead Oct-Sep.

Is that interpretation correct?

How can I reorder them for plotting?

How can I achieve the creating the [multiyearmean as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463146/how-to-compute-the-average-value-for-a-each-day-of-the-year-from-multi-year-data?noredirect=1#comment93798636_53463146) without breaking my date sequence?

Comment: I have to ask: why? If the dates are within one calendar year, this just sounds like a confusing and misleading visualisation.

Comment: This is for the purposes of representing rainfall data, which is a context wherein the "hydrological year" is a preferred unit of time to the "calendar year". So the plot should begin Oct 1 and end Sep 30. But the dataframe runs Jan 1 to Dec 30, since the dates are ordered ascending or descending by default.

Comment: It would help to see some example data from the data frame. `ggplot2` should have no problem with dates, but it rather depends how dates are defined in your data.

Comment: If the dates are "ordered by default" they mustn't have the previous and "current" year set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Original answer created fake data since none originally provided in OP. Now uses suggested `df` example data. (Thanks for adding, btw! Simplifies answering.)

I'd suggest adjusting your dates so they are a continuous range from one Oct 1 through the next Sept 30. That way you can plot in `ggplot` using dates, but with the alignment you prefer.

For instance, taking your data, we could adjust it to all go into one Oct-Sep year (ending 2020 so we capture Feb 29's).

```
df2b <- df %>%
  mutate(date_hydro = lubridate::ymd(paste(
    if_else(month(Date) < 10, 2020, 2019), # 2020 is leap year
    month(Date), day(Date))
  )) %>%
group_by(date_hydro) %>%
summarize(multiyearmean = mean(Val))
```

Then we can plot the daily averages within the hydrological year.

```
ggplot(df2b, aes(date_hydro, multiyearmean)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "1 month", 
               minor_breaks = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated, but please see my edit as I believe it indicates that this solution will not suffice.

Comment: Updated. I think the simplest thing is to re-express each date as its equivalent within the 2019-2020 hydrological year, then average according to those adjusted dates.

Comment: Your "multiyearmean" solution works perfectly and basically obviates the problem that prompted me to ask this question about shifting the start point of the X-axis. However, that is probably the appropriate way to deal with this issue, so I am giving you the answer.

Comment: Reputation or something is preventing me from answering my other  "multiyearmean" question, but your code above is the preferred solution, so I'll give you the answer over there if you post it, @JonSpring. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463146/how-to-compute-the-average-value-for-a-each-day-of-the-year-from-multi-year-data

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat similar to the other answer but using your simulation:

```
set.seed(2018 - 11 - 25) # reproducible data

data.frame(
  dates = seq(as.Date("2000-10-01"), as.Date("2010-10-01"), by = "days"),
  values = runif(3653)
) -> xdf

mutate(
  xdf, 
  day = lubridate::day(dates), 
  month = lubridate::month(dates)
) %>%
  group_by(month, day) %>%
  summarize(multi_year_mean = mean(values)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(plot_date = case_when( # use "real" date axis and wrap-around 
    month >= 10 ~ as.Date(sprintf("2019-%02s-%02s", month, day)),
    TRUE ~ as.Date(sprintf("2020-%02s-%02s", month, day)) # account for leap year(s)
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(plot_date, multi_year_mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0.75), date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") # adjust aesthetics as necessary
```

[image]